# Python - How to read from long-running subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Reading from a long-running subprocess seems to be possible, but I can only get it to work if the subprocess is `python3 -i`:

```
>>> sub = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-i'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> sub.stdin.write(b'2+3\n')
4
>>> sub.stdin.flush()
>>> sub.stdout.readline()
b'5\n'
```

Attempting the same thing with a small echo program does not work:

```
>>> sub = subprocess.Popen(['./echo'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> sub.stdin.write(b'2+3\n')
4
>>> sub.stdin.flush()
>>> sub.stdout.readline()
^ Hangs here until interrupted with Ctrl-C
```

`echo` reads from STDIO and echoes when it gets a newline. It works fine when run directly. Here is the code for it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char message[64];
  uint8_t cursor = 0;
  
  while(true) {
    read(STDIN_FILENO, message + cursor, 1);
    
    if(message[cursor++] == '\n') {
      message[cursor] = 0;
      printf(message);
      cursor = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried a few other techniques like `.communicate()` with similar results. Oddly, `subprocess.Popen(['python3'], ...)` fails where the same call works when running `python3 -i`, even though `python3` and `python3 -i` seem to do the same thing when run at the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be buffering within the subprocess' stdout. I solved it by setting line-buffering using `setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 1024);`. If no buffering at all is desired, `setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` can be used.